# How do I map an associative array to html element attributes?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a basic form building class to speed my workflow up a bit and I'd like to be able to take an array of attributes like so:

```
$attributes = array(
   "type"         => "text",
   "id"           => "contact-name",
   "name"         => "contact-name",
   "required"     => true
);
```

and map that to the attributes of a html element:

```
<input type="text" id="contact-name" name="contact-name" required />
```

EDIT:

What is the cleanest way of achieving the above? I'm sure I could cobble something together with a loop and some concatenation but I get the feeling printf or similar could do it in a more elegant manner.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: So if you have build such a class, you probably tried something? And what @nostrzak said ;)

Comment: I did not get it, where is the problem, or what actually do you wanna do :]

Comment: the question is how do I map the array to the HTML elements, was that not clear?

Comment: Do you want to generate the HTML as per the array?

Comment: Use Zend Form http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html and get on with something else useful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$attrs = join(' ', array_map(function($key) use ($attributes){
    if(is_bool($attributes[$key])){
        return $attributes[$key]?$key:'';
    }
    return $key.'="'.$attributes[$key].'"';
}, array_keys($attributes)));

$result = '<input ' . $attrs . ' />';
```

Comment: Also I want to notice that attribute values should be escaped before outputting if they are taken from untrusted source (i.e. user input).

Comment: You can use `rtrim()` to remove whitespace at the last attribute :D

Answer (score 14):

```
$attr = array(
    'type'     => 'text',
    'id'       => 'contact-name',
    'name'     => 'contact-name',
    'required' => true,
    'value'    => '" <b>html</b> \'test\''
);

echo '<input '. implode(' ', array_map(
    function ($k, $v) { return $k .'="'. htmlspecialchars($v) .'"'; },
    array_keys($attr), $attr
)) .' />';
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines (a very simple method -- of course you can extend this, but this will provide you with the basic functionality):

```
$output = "<input ";
foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
    $output .= $key.'="'.$value.'" ';
}
$output .= "/>";
```

Comment: I've submitted an edit that adds support for boolean elements as his question demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks, the boolean element is of particular interest.

Comment: Depending on what HTML you want, booleans might not be required. HTML5 is like your example, XHTML however must be `required="required"`.

Comment: Just as a comment on the booleans, if you add this snippet: `if(is_bool($value)) { $value = ($value) ? "true" : "false"; }` inside the ***foreach*** loop above the `$output` line, it should convert booleans into strings for use in attributes. Note what @EduardLuca said above though however, that booleans may not be required.

Answer (score 5):

As http_build_query is meant for *stringify* associative array's, I hoped to stumble upon such a solution here. Didn't find one, so here's my 'one-liner':

```
$output = '<input ' . str_replace( '=', '="', http_build_query( $attributes, '', '" ') ) . '" />';
```

Unfortunately:

1. it converts boolean-values to 1/0 (instead of ommiting them if false, which can be achieved by using array_filter, but results in double function-calls);
2. doesn't handle array's in a desired way;
3. Needs `urldecode` after `http_build_query` to get back the encoded spaces (for example, when having multiple html-classes in an attribute).

So, only suitable in certain situations!

Comment: class attribute would fail if multiple due to spaces; `$attributes = str_replace( [ '=', '+' ], [ '="', ' ' ], http_build_query( $attributes, null, '" ') );`

Comment: That's correct as I pointed out in footnote 3, together with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = '<input ';

foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
    if (is_bool($value)) {
        if ($value) $output .= $name . ' ';
    } else {
        $output .= sprintf('%s="%s"', $name, $value);
    }
}

$output .= '>';
```

For XHTML change

```
    if ($value) $output .= $name . ' ';
```

to

```
    if ($value) $output .= sprintf('%s="%s"', $name, $name);
```

and

```
    $output .= '>';
```

to

```
    $output .= '/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I use in my projects:

```
function html_attributes($attributes)
{
    if(!$attributes) return '';

    $compiled = join('="%s" ', array_keys($attributes)).'="%s"';

    return vsprintf($compiled, array_map('htmlspecialchars', array_values($attributes)));
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer years ago and I just needed this again. Still the coolest answer here imo. That said, I think you could drop the `rtrim(` by removing the last space in the appended `.'="%s"'`.

Comment: @Ortho you are absolutely right, I updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_attrs = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'placeholder' => 'Placeholder',
    'value' => 'the value'
);

//Use & for modify current item in array
array_walk($input_attrs, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item =  $key . '="' . $item . '"';
});

$input = '<input '. implode(' ', $input_attrs) .' />';
```

Comment: A blob of code for an answer is not great, especially with all the noisy answers already given to an incomplete question. Maybe some context?

Answer (score 1):

This method generates Html attributes based on an associative array. It also supports arrays as the value (for multi-valued attributes like class), boolean values, html special characters, trims, and removes empty values.

```
function htmlAttributes($attributes)
{

    if (!$attributes) return '';

    // handle boolean, array, & html special chars
    array_walk($attributes, function (&$value, $key) {
        $value = is_bool($value) ? $value ? 1 : 0 : $value;
        $value = is_array($value) ? implode(' ', $value) : $value;
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    });

    // remove empty elements
    $attributes = array_filter($attributes, function ($value) {
        return strlen($value) > 0;
    });

    if (!$attributes) return '';

    $compiled = implode('="%s" ', array_keys($attributes)) . '="%s"';
    return vsprintf($compiled, array_values($attributes));
}

$attributes = array(
   'type'         => 'text',
   'id'           => 'id',
   'name'         => 'contact-name',
   'required'     => true,
   'class'        => ['class-1', 'class-2'],
   'data-active'  => false,
   'data-markup   => '" <b>html</b> \'test\'',
   'data-value'   => '',
   'data-values'  => []

);

echo htmlAttributes($attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school PHP 4 - 5.2 version. This also allows for an array for the `class` attribute.

```
$attributes = array(
    "type"         => "text",
    "class"        => array("one", "two"),
    "id"           => "contact-name",
    "name"         => "contact-name",
    "required"     => true
);

printf(
    '<input %s />', 
    join(' ', array_map('mapAttr', array_keys($attr), array_values($attr)))
);

function mapAttr($key, $value) {
   if (is_array($value)) {
      return mapAttr($key, join(' ', $value));
   }
   if (is_bool($value)) {
      return $value ? $key : '';
   }
   return sprintf('%s="%s"', $key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one:

```
function html_attributes(array $array) {
    return implode(' ', array_map(function ($key, $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = implode(' ', $value);
        }

        return $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '"';
    }, array_keys($array), $array));
}
```

This one allow to use array of attribute's value. Ex.

```
$attrs = [
    'class' => ['foo', 'bar'],
    'id' => 'baz',
];

echo html_attributes($attrs);
// -> `class="foo bar" id="baz"`
```

'hope it helps someone! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function createDomElement($tag, $attributes, $inner = '', $closingTag = true)
{
    return '<' . $tag . ' ' . rtrim(join(' ', array_map(function ($key) use ($attributes) {
        return is_bool($attributes[$key]) ? $attributes[$key] : $key . '="' . $attributes[$key] . '"';
    }, array_keys($attributes)))) . '>' . $inner . ($closingTag ? '</' . $tag . '>' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution, hope it helps!

- Used === to check for the boolean and that it's true in a single check
- Used addslashes to escape double-quotes on value being placed inside double-quotes
- Looped on the array itself and updated its own values in preparation for implode
- Imploded the values together with a space which means there is no need to trim any white space. Any values turned into '' as a result of the boolean check would simply not show up.

Seems shorter too.

```
foreach($attr as $k=>$v){
    $attr[$k] = $v===true?$k:"$k=\"".addslashes($v)."\"";
}
echo "<input ".implode(" ",$attr)." />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I didn't see yet, using [php's `array_reduce`](https://php.net/array_reduce).

```php
    <?php
    $attributeCollection = [
        'speed' => 'slow',
        'ball' => false,
        'globe' => true,
    ];
    $attributes = array_reduce(
            array_keys( $attributeCollection ) ,
            fn( $carry , $name ) => vsprintf(
                '%s %s="%s"' , [
                    $carry ,
                    $name ,
                    $attributeCollection[ $name ] ,
                ])
        )
    $markup = '<marquee' . $attributes . '></blink>';
    echo $markup;
```

Using a function

```php
    <?php
    function attributes (?array $in = null): string
    {
        $in ??= [];
        $out = '';
        $out .= array_reduce(
            array_keys( $in ) ,
            fn( $carry , $name ) => vsprintf(
                    '%s %s="%s"' ,
                    [
                        $carry ,
                        $name ,
                        $in[ $name ] ,
                    ]
                )
        );
        return $out;
    }

    $attributes = [
        'speed' => 'slow',
        'ball' => false,
        'globe' => true,
    ];
    $markup = '<marquee' . attributes( $attributes ) . '></blink>';
    echo $markup;
```

Supporting booleans

```php
    <?php
    function attributes (?array $in = null): string
    {
        $in ??= [];
        $out = '';
        $out .= array_reduce(
            array_keys( $in ) ,
            fn( $carry , $name ) => is_bool($in[$name]) && true !== $in[$name]
            # fn( $carry , $name ) => !$in[$name]
               ? $carry
               : vsprintf(
                    '%s %s="%s"' ,
                    [
                        $carry ,
                        $name ,
                        is_bool($in[$name]) ? $name : $in[ $name ] ,
                    ]
                )
        );
        return $out;
    }

    $attributes = [
        'speed' => 'slow',
        'ball' => false,
        'globe' => true,
    ];
    $markup = '<marquee' . attributes( $attributes ) . '></blink>';
    echo $markup;
```